# How to release the Blackberry Applications in Market

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I Developed some applications on blackberry then i need to release this applications in market please help me how to release the application in market, what are the process and other details

Thanking you..

Answer (score 1):

How about [Blackberry AppWorld](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/)? You can use Blackberry's virtual store (similar to Apple AppStore) to make your application available to Blackberry Users.

Check their website out for information of the process of submitting an application to it.

Comment: Also if you are looking to deploy it in an Enterprise setting or want to allow it to be downloaded from a hosted location, have a look at this document http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/2733/Deploying_Java_Applications.pdf